# Where is the "right" place to copy applications and scripts so they are accessible to every user on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, users, shares

I'm configuring a build machine using Ubuntu 9.10 Desktop as the platform.  The first user and of course admin is "developer", and then I created lots of user accounts so people could access shares and other services on the machine.  I've got to provide developers with access to certain scripts and SDKs.  So, I created a folder in the developer's home directory and added other users to the developer group.  This works, but I think it may not be proper.  I believe there may be a proper, common place to store (not necessarily installable) applications, scripts, and other resources that make them available to all users.  Is there a "right" directory for storing applications to make them accessible to all users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[/usr/local](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY)

The link is to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard which reads, in part, "The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally."